# Formatting a mysql number from a select statement into php

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, formatting

I am using mysql 5.1 database and have a # of fields in them that look like this for format:

1234567

When I output them to via php, I would like them formatted like this:
1,234,567

There are no decimals involved.

The select statement is pulling 30 records from my database.  Each record has (2) fields that I need formatted thus.  Weight and Cost as well as 16 other fields that I need, but do not need formatting.  They are being read and entered int a table.

Suggestions?

Note:
Data Fields:  Cost Weight 
Table: Warships
Current Select statement:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `Warships` WHERE `Type` = "BC" ');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SHIP CLASS'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['CAT'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['WEIGHT'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Cost'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: You can use PHP function: http://codepad.org/5I0emK75

Answer (score 1):

I think PHP's number_format is what you need.

```
$num = number_format(1234567);
echo $num; // 1,234,567
```

If only one parameter is given, number will be formatted without decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands. [More info from PHP API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Thanks!  The number_format was what I needed.  Many thanks to all for their help!!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function. Pass your number to it as the first parameter and it will add in a comma for the thousands separator.

Example:

```
echo "<td>" . number_format($row['Cost']) . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

[number format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$num_format = number_format(1234567);
echo $num_format ; // 1,234,567
```